# how to send data from a php file to another php file?

Tags: php

i am making a "login and signup form" actions for my file. i searched about this many times but i cant find the answer and most of the topics are about sql which i don't use for these files.
im looking for a answer without `include`, `sql`, or `session` in my files
here's my codes

html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Gleacc</title>

        <!-- Load external CSS styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Gleacc GG</h1>
        <br>
        <form action="data/signedup.php" method="get">
            <label for="usn">
                <input placeholder="Username" name="usn" required>
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for="psw">
                <input placeholder="Password" name="psw" required>
            </label>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <!-- Load external JavaScript -->
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

signuped. php:

```
<?php 
$psw = $_GET['psw'];
$usn = $_GET['usn'];
echo "<form action="data/logined.php" method="post"><input placeholder="Username" name="usn" required><br><input placeholder="Password" name="psw" required><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>";
?>
```

logined.php: none since we cant compair the input because we cant get the $usn and $psw from signuped.php

Comment: "looking for a answer without include, sql, or session" Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being silly.

1. Are the users signing up every time they are on the website?  If not, then you need to save their username and password in some sort of database.
2. Any other method used in **signuped** is exposing data that you shouldn't be exposing.

Here is one way to do what you want and make it a tad secure.

```php
<?php 
$psw = encrypt($_POST['psw']);
$usn = encrypt($_POST['usn']);

echo "<form action='data/logined.php' method='post'>
<input placeholder='Username' name='usn' required><br>
<input placeholder='Password' name='psw' required><br>
<input class='hidden' value='$usn' name='encusn'><br>
<input class='hidden' value='$psw' name='encpsw'><br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
?>
```

Where you use **CSS** to hide the two inputs.  Be warned that it is not hard to expose them in the browser by anyone with even a little knowledge of CSS.

In your **logined** file you encrypt the entered values and compare them with encrypted values from the hidden inputs.  I wouldn't use a two-way algorithm and try to decrypt the encrypted values.

Comment: Unless this is for a class project or something you should never be using $_GET for peoples passwords lol

Comment: @JDawwgy - Oops, I had just copied the OPs statements, without thinking.  He is submitting a form, so they should have been POST anyway.  Even with the POST, I have put a warning there.  I certainly would not do any of those stages this way.  And my first statement summaries it.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that signuped.php is placed inside the folder data which placed same level as the html file.
then change the action in the html file from get to post and try var_dump($_POST) to see if the inputs has been submited.

Comment: Ask the original poster how they are sending the data or provide an answer that covers the different ways. Is it by $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION or some other way? Once the method is establish, the perhaps an explanation as to how to submit (ie, the Form structure if that's what it being used) would be helpful. Clearly the poster is new at programming so needs very basic help just to get started.